# Homomorphisms of a Finite Group & Perfect Squares

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I'm working on a textbook problem:

Come up with a finite group $G$ and homomorphism: $f: G \rightarrow G$ such that $3$% of the elements of in $G$ satisfy $f(x) = x^2$ (where $x$ is an element in $G$).

So far, I've tried a lot of different ideas. When I made the binary operator for $G$ additive, I had a tough time since the homomorphism must follow a lot of conditions such as $f(2) = 2f(1)$, not leaving a lot of space for me to try and come up with a way to get $f(x) = x^2.$

I tried making the group a power group and multiplicative. In both scenarios, I didn't really get anything too useful – every idea that I tried ultimately failed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution where I explain all the "false starts" I tried along the way. Let's start by looking at a very simple example, namely the multiplication-by-$m$ map $f(x) = mx$ on the cyclic group $C_n \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$ (written additively). The subset of elements satisfying $f(x) = mx = 2x$ is the subset of elements satisfying $(m-2) x = 0$, which has size $\gcd(m-2, n)$ (exercise). So the density of this subset is $\frac{\gcd(m-2, n)}{n}$, which unfortunately as a fraction in lowest terms always has numerator $1$ and so cannot be equal to $\frac{3}{100}$. So no example of this form can work.

The next group I tried was $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$, but I ran into the following problem generalizing the previous observation: if $A$ is any abelian group and $f : A \to A$ is a homomorphism then the subset of elements satisfying $f(a) = 2a$ is $\text{ker}(f - 2)$ which is a subgroup, so its density always has numerator $1$ when written as a fraction in lowest terms (with denominator the index). This means an example must be nonabelian.

However, abelian examples do help us for the following reason: if $f_1 : G_1 \to G_1$ is an endomorphism of a group and $f_2 : G_2 \to G_2$ is an endomorphism of another group, we can take their direct product to get an endomorphism $f_1 \times f_2 : G_1 \times G_2 \to G_1 \times G_2$. If we write $d(G, f)$ for the density of elements satisfying $f(g) = g^2$, then

$$d(G_1 \times G_2, f_1 \times f_2) = d(G_1, f_1) d(G_2, f_2).$$

So when we're looking for nonabelian examples it suffices to find a nonabelian group with density of the form $\frac{3}{n}$ where $n \mid 100$, and then we can take the direct product with a suitable abelian group to get density $\frac{3}{100}$.

If $f : G \to G$ is a complicated endomorphism of a complicated nonabelian group then it could be quite hard to count the number of elements satisfying $f(g) = g^2$, so for starters let's see what happens if we just set $f(g) = e$ to be the zero endomorphism. Then we're counting the elements satisfying $g^2 = e$, which when $G$ is nonabelian need not be a subgroup. For example, $G = S_3$ has $4$ such elements, with density $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$, which does not have numerator $1$, so this is promising.

Let's see if we can get density $\frac{3}{4}$. The smallest possible example with this property would be a group of order $8$, so let's consider the dihedral group $D_4$. The dihedral group consists of a copy of $C_4$, of which $2$ elements square to the identity, plus $4$ reflections, all of which square to the identity, so the density is $\frac{6}{8} = \frac{3}{4}$ as desired.

So we're done. We can take our final group $G$ to be $\boxed{ D_4 \times C_{25} }$ and our final endomorphism to be $\boxed{ f(g, h) = (e, h) }$.

Comment: Well done! I wasted a lot of time on this, but I had misread the question, and I was looking for automorphism $f$ of $G$. I suspect that is not possible.

Comment: @Derek: that does seem a lot trickier! If $f(g) = e$ hadn't worked I might've tried taking $f$ to be an inner automorphism next.

Comment: when working with the abelian groups, you talked about $f(a) = 2a$. Is this a typo? Shouldn't it have been $f(a) = a^n$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @delhimaths: I’m just writing the group operation additively. It means the same thing.

Comment: why does it mean the same thing? I don't really understand

Comment: @delhimaths: if $m$ denotes the group operation, squaring refers to $m(g, g)$. If you write the group operation multiplicatively this is $g \times g = g^2$. If you write the group operation additively this is $g + g = 2g$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but doesn't the original problem statement just say ()=2? Shouldn't that mean that even if it was an additive group, if I put 3 into the function, I should get 9 and not 6?

Comment: @delhimaths: for a group, $g^2$ always refers to $m(g, g)$ where $m$ is the group operation and sometimes has to be inferred from context. $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is not a group under multiplication, only under addition, and the problem refers only to groups, which can be written either additively (for abelian groups) or multiplicatively

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the help! I'm curious – do you know how to figure out what the largest possible value of $k$ could be? I know that in order to get it, we would need to have a group that cannot be written as a direct product of other groups. But after that, I don't really see a way to maximize it.

Comment: @delhimaths: sorry, what is $k$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh my bad. I think when it got edited by Shaun, he removed it. $k$ is just the percent of elements that satisfy $f(x) = x^2.$ So in this example, you gave a group with $k = 75$%. On the other thread that I made about partioning a group into smaller sets, I had asked that because I wanted to see if I could just say that all groups can be written as cyclic, dihedral, symmetric groups (or maybe some other super simple/very often used type of group) so that it would be easiest to maximize $k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan When you tried $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$, shouldn't the density just be the density of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ squared based off of the formula you gave right after ($d(G_1 \times G_2, f_1 \times f_2) = d(G_1, f_1) d(G_2, f_2).$)?

Comment: @delhimaths: that formula only applies to an endomorphism of the form $f_1 \times f_2$. Generally an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ is given by a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: @delhimaths: as for your other question, groups are much more complicated than that, and I don't know what the highest density could be. As in my previous comment, it doesn't follow that the group can't be written as a direct product because the endomorphism can "mix" the two factors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ and $f_1 \times f_2$? Also, what would such a matrix look like? Do you of any source that talks about this?

Comment: @delhimaths: one of those is a group and one of those is an endomorphism. The "diagonal" endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ of the form $f_1 \times f_2$ are precisely the ones which, when viewed as $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/n$, correspond to diagonal matrices. And there are lots of non-diagonal matrices, such as $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$, which corresponds to the endomorphism $(a, b) \mapsto (a, a + b)$. I don't know of any sources that talk about this specifically; these are basically exercises.

Comment: (That is, the exercise: show that every endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ is given by multiplication by a unique $2 \times 2$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/n$. You can prove a more general version of this for endomorphisms of the direct product / sum $A \times B$ of two arbitrary abelian groups also.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It looks like this question, along with every single other question the same user has asked, came directly from the [MIT PRIMES 2021 application](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2021/entpro21.pdf). Flagging them all would create a lot of work for moderators, and I think accomplish very little, since this answer and others have already been up for a while. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Misha: oof. Well, at the very least PRIMES should be notified. Do you want to do it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay. I've sent them an email.